# Prove $\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} \lt \arctan x$ for every $x \gt 0$

Tags: calculus

> Prove $$\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} \lt \arctan x$$ for every $x \gt 0$.

I proved half of it with lagrange rule but that I got stuck. Any ideas?

I can upload my work if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let be 
$\displaystyle f:[0,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $

$f(x)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} - \arctan x$

$\displaystyle f'(x)=\frac{x' \cdot \sqrt{1+x^2} - x \cdot (\sqrt{1+x^2})'}{(\sqrt{1+x^2})^2} -(\arctan x)'$

$\displaystyle f'(x)=\frac{1 \cdot \sqrt{1+x^2} - x \cdot \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{1+x^2}}\cdot 2 \cdot x}{(\sqrt{1+x^2})^2} - \frac{1}{1+x^2}$

$\displaystyle f'(x)=\frac{ \sqrt{1+x^2} - \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} }{{1+x^2}} - \frac{1}{1+x^2}$

$\displaystyle f'(x)=\frac{ \frac{1+x^2}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} - \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} -1}{{1+x^2}} $

$\displaystyle f'(x)=\frac{ 1+x^2-x^2 -\sqrt{1+x^2} }{{(1+x^2) \cdot \sqrt{1+x^2}}} $

$f'(x)=\frac{1-\sqrt{1+x^2}}{(1+x^2)\sqrt{1+x^2}} <0$

because $f'(x) <0$ we have that $f$ is decreasing on $ [0,\infty)$ 
and thus

$f(0)>f(x)$ for any $x$ in $ (0,\infty)$

but $f(0)=0$, so

$0>f(x)$

$0>\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} - \arctan x$

$\arctan x>\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$

Comment: We differnetiate just to prove that we can say $f(0) = 0$? so then we can "safely" say that $ 0 > f(x) $ ? and what rule are you using here?

Comment: using $f'(x)<0$ we prove that f is decreasing

Comment: so $f(0)>f(x)$ for all $x>0$ and because $f(0)=0$ we can say that $0>f(x)$ for all $x>0$

Comment: Perfect. So we didn't you any lagrange / any other rules here?

Comment: we used just the fact that function f defined above is decreasing on $(0, \infty)$  so $f(0)>f(x)$

Comment: I made some edits to solution, I think now is more clear

Answer (score 2):

Let $x=\tan\theta$ with $0\lt\theta\lt\pi/2$.  Since $\sqrt{1+\tan^2\theta}=\sec\theta$ on the left and $\arctan(\tan\theta)=\theta$ on the right, the given inequality is equivalent to the inequality

$$\sin\theta\lt\theta\quad\text{for }0\lt\theta\lt\pi/2$$

Answer (score 2):

**METHODOLOGY $1$:**

The integral definition of the arctangent function is given by

$$\arctan(x)=\int_0^x \frac{1}{1+t^2}\,dt$$

Noting that for $t\in [0,x]$, $x\ge 0$, $1+t^2\le (1+t^2)^{3/2}$, we can assert

$$\arctan(x)\ge \int_0^x \frac{1}{(1+t^2)^{3/2}}\,dt=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$$

and we are done!

---

**METHODOLOGY $2$:**
Recall from basic geometry the inequality for the sine function

$$\sin y\le y \tag 1$$

for $y\ge 0$.  From $(1)$ it is easy to see that for $0\le y<1$, we have

$$\cos y\ge \sqrt{1-y^2} \tag 2$$

Taking $(1)$ and $(2)$ together reveals that for $0\le y<1$

$$\tan y\le \frac{y}{\sqrt{1-y^2}} \tag 3$$

Now, let $x=\frac{y}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}$.  Note that for $0\le y<1$, $x>0$ and

$$y=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} \tag 4$$

Using $(4)$ in $(3)$, we obtain

$$\tan\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\right)\le x$$

Taking the inverse function yields the desired inequality

$$\arctan(x)\ge \frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion: Take $f(x) = \arctan x - {x\over (1+x^2)^{1/2}}$. What is $f(0)$? What is the sign of $f'(x)$ for $x> 0 $? Does that give a lower bound on $f(x)$ for $x> 0$?

Answer (score 1):

For $x=0$ we have equality. Then, deriving, for $x>0$ we have

$$\frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}-\dfrac{x^2}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}}{1+x^2}=\frac1{(1+x^2)^{3/2}}<\frac1{1+x^2}$$ and the LHS grows slowlier than the RHS.

---

The main "trick" is to use differentiation to let the transcendental function disappear.